# Fill missing value based on probability of occurrence

Tags: r, data.table, missing-data

This is what my data.table/dataframe looks lke

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
   STATE     ZIP      
   PA        19333        
   PA        19327        
   PA        19333        
   PA        NA        
   PA        19355
   PA        19333
   PA        NA
   PA        19355
   PA        NA     
')
```

I have three missing values in the `ZIP` column. I want to fill the missing values with nonmissing sample values of `ZIPs` according to their probability of occuring in the dataset. So for example ZIP 19333 occurs three times in the dataset and ZIP 19355 occurs twice in the dataset and 19327 occurs once. So ZIP 19333 has 50% probability of occurring in the dataset for `PA`, and 19355 has a 33.33% chance and 19327 has a 16.17% chance of occurring.  So 19333 has the highest probability of being picked in trying to fill the three missing ZIPs. The final filled dataset may look like the following where two missing values are filled by '19333' and one was filled by '19355':

```
       STATE     ZIP      
       PA        19333        
       PA        19327        
       PA        19333        
       PA        19333       
       PA        19355
       PA        19333
       PA        19333
       PA        19355
       PA        19355
```

I have more than one `STATE` in my dataset. The main idea is to fill in missing ZIPs based on the probability of a ZIP occurring for a given `STATE`.

Comment: Are you asking about your code or your method for determining missing values? Do you have data for more than one state? I assume you don't want to fill in all missing values for all states with the same zip code. It's a bit unclear to me exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your comment. I made some edits. Hopefully, the post is more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way just using `sample`, wrapped up in a convenience function.

```
sample_fill_na = function(x) {
    x_na = is.na(x)
    x[x_na] = sample(x[!x_na], size = sum(x_na), replace = TRUE)
    return(x)
}

dt[, ZIP := sample_fill_na(ZIP), by = STATE]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. Sometimes the sample function can draw 19355 for all three missing values. Is there a way to force proportional draws from the sample of non-null ZIPs?

Comment: It is sampling randomly based on the probability of a ZIP occurring for a given state. Proportional fills are not well defined. How would you want to fill the following examples? `(1, 1, 2, 2, NA)`? `(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA)`? `(1, 2, 3, NA, NA)`? etc.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend reading up a little on imputation - a nice way to approach the problem might be to repeat whatever analysis you are doing `n` times, with different random fills of the data each time. Comparing the distribution of the results will quantify how sensitive your results are to the imputation, and averaging them will give you a more robust estimate. In any single run, you can use `set.seed()` for reproducibility of the random draws (just don't use the same seed if you want different random draws!).