# Replace NA values in a column in dataframe based on probability of occurrence with non-NA values

Tags: r, random, data.table

I have to populate a set of 'Failure' values within a 'Bucket' randomly.

For instance,

```
| Bucket | Failure | Id |
|--------|---------|----|
| B1     | F1      | 1  |
| B1     | F2      | 2  |
| B1     | F1      | 3  |
| B1     | null    | 4  |
| B1     | null    | 5  |
| B2     | F3      | 6  |
| B2     | F4      | 7  |
| B2     | null    | 8  |
```

In table above, each Bucket can contain many records. Some of those records will contain Failure populated, but most will not. My goal is to randomly assign the Failure based on the proportion of Failures within a bucket. For instance, for combination - {B1, F1} as compared to the proportion of B1 records(with Failure populated) is 2/3 **and** for {B1, F2} the proportion of B1 records(with failure populated) is 1/3.

Therefore the records of B1 with **null** Failure column (Id=4,5) should get randomly either failure F1 or F2 but with the same proportion of F1 as 2/3 and F2 as 1/3. This logic needs to be applied for all buckets within the table.

I see that this is a complicated thing. I'm relatively a R noob, therefore, any code examples would be much appreciated.

In between, I see this question. But the solution doesn't  run:  [Fill missing value based on probability of occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143523/fill-missing-value-based-on-probability-of-occurrence)

**See sample code:**

```
test <- data.frame(
bucket = c(rep('B1', 5), rep('B2',3))
    , failure = c('F1', 'F2', 'F1', NA, NA, 'F3', 'F4', NA)
    , Id = seq(1:8)
)

test

sample_fill_na = function(x) {
    x_na = is.na(x)
    x[x_na] = sample(x[!x_na], size = sum(x_na), replace = TRUE)
    return(x)
}

test[, failure := sample_fill_na(failure), by = bucket]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, we can use the `probs` argument in the `sample` function, and create weights (`sample` converts it to probabilities for us) using the `table` function.

Hope this helps!

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.frame(bucket = c(rep('B1', 5), rep('B2',3)), failure = c('F1', 'F2', 'F1', NA, NA, 'F3', 'F4', NA), Id = seq(1:8))

fillF <- function(x){
  y <- table(x)
  x[is.na(x)] <- sample(names(y),sum(is.na(x)),prob =y,replace=T)
  return(x)
}

setDT(test)[, failure := fillF(failure), by = bucket]
```

output:

```
   bucket failure Id
1:     B1      F1  1
2:     B1      F2  2
3:     B1      F1  3
4:     B1      F1  4
5:     B1      F1  5
6:     B2      F3  6
7:     B2      F4  7
8:     B2      F3  8
```

---

We can easily check the proportions with the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:9){test=rbind(test,test)}
setDT(test)[, failure := fillF(failure), by = bucket]
table(test$failure)
```

And indeed, the proportions look alright:

```
  F1   F2   F3   F4 
1705  855  749  787
```

---

EDIT: If there are empty groups in your data, we ave to decide on probbilities for ourselves. There are two logical options, fill always with a default (e.g. `F1`), or randomly sample from all options. So:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.frame(bucket = c(rep('B1', 5), rep('B2',3),'B3'), failure = c('F1', 'F2', 'F1', NA, NA, 'F3', 'F4', NA,NA), Id = seq(1:9))

fillF <- function(x){
  y <- table(x)
  if(sum(y)<1){y=c('F1'=1)} # always F1
  # if(sum(y)<1){y=y+1} # randomly sample from all possibilities
  x[is.na(x)] <- sample(names(y),sum(is.na(x)),prob =y,replace=T)
  return(x)
}

setDT(test)[, failure := fillF(failure), by = bucket]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. But, I have a problem/question. Before, I populate the NA values, if I backup the failure column into a different column, that column's NA values also gets replaced. For instance before I run the setDT function, if I backup the failure in a new column test$failureNA <- test$failure, this failureNA column also gets replaced.

Comment: That is because the column reference is the same. Try `test$failureNA <- copy(test$failure)` instead of `test$failureNA <- test$failure`.

Comment: Thanks again. But, I'm getting an error: **Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob): too few positive probabilities** in sample(names(y), sum(is.na(x)), prob = y, replace = T)

Comment: That is because there are issues with your data. There is a group with no F values, so how would we know how to fill the missing values? For one possibility see the edit in my answer (always fill with F1). Hope that helps.

Comment: I worked around the problem of too few probabilities, but separately assign the Failure value whenever there was only one possible Failure for a bucket. Otherwise, the solution is good. **Florian, can you please adjust your solution so that the failure is not hard-coded to F1. I don't know how to do that..**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution, it basically sample the failures with the probability given by their proportion in each bucket.

```
test <- data.frame(
  bucket = c(rep('B1', 5), rep('B2',3))
  , failure = c('F1', 'F2', 'F1', NA, NA, 'F3', 'F4', NA)
  , Id = seq(1:8)
)

fillNA <- function(test) {
  uni <- unique(test$bucket)
  for (i in 1:length(uni)) {
    pos <- test$bucket == uni[i]
    tbl <- table(test[pos, 2])
    proportions <- tbl / sum(tbl)
    posNA <- pos & is.na(test[, 2])
    test[posNA, 2] <- sample(levels(test[, 2]), 
                             sum(posNA),
                             replace = TRUE,
                             prob = proportions)
  }
  return(test)
}
fillNA(test)
```

Result:

```
 bucket failure Id
1     B1      F1  1
2     B1      F2  2
3     B1      F1  3
4     B1      F1  4
5     B1      F1  5
6     B2      F3  6
7     B2      F4  7
8     B2      F4  8
```