# how to fill in values based on highest occurrence of combinations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a huge df that looks some what like this -

```
...   ||    City     ||  Country
           Newyork        USA
           Newyork        USA
           Newyork        USA
           Newyork        **unknown**
           delhi          india
           delhi          **unknown**
           delhi          india
```

Now, I want to fill in the unknowns with the correct country based on what cities have already been matched. For example, most rows with newyork have been USA in country column.

My idea was to group by country and convert it into a dictionary to map, but that sort of failed.

> Here's a simillar question asked but the solution is in R:
>   [Fill missing value based on probability of occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143523/fill-missing-value-based-on-probability-of-occurrence)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using `collections.Counter` to find the most common `Country` for the `'**unknown**'` fields based on a `groupby('City')`.

```
from collections import Counter
def MC(a):
    return a.replace('**unknown**', Counter(a).most_common()[0][0])

df.Country = df.groupby('City').Country.apply(MC)
print(df)

#      City Country
# 0  Newyork     USA
# 1  Newyork     USA
# 2  Newyork     USA
# 3  Newyork     USA
# 4    delhi   india
# 5    delhi   india
# 6    delhi   india
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with first index or first value of [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) per groups with `replace`:

```
def f(x):
    #remove '**unknown**' rows and get top1 value
    return x.replace('**unknown**', x[x.ne('**unknown**')].value_counts().index[0])
    #return x.replace('**unknown**', x[x.ne('**unknown**')].mode().iat[0])

df['Country'] = df.groupby('City')['Country'].apply(f)
print (df)
      City Country
0  Newyork     USA
1  Newyork     USA
2  Newyork     USA
3  Newyork     USA
4    delhi   india
5    delhi   india
6    delhi   india
```

Another solution is replace `**unknown**` to missing values, get top value and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace('**unknown**', np.nan)

s = df.groupby('City')['Country'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
#alternative
#s = df.groupby('City')['Country'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
df['Country'] = df['Country'].fillna(s)
print (df)
      City Country
0  Newyork     USA
1  Newyork     USA
2  Newyork     USA
3  Newyork     USA
4    delhi   india
5    delhi   india
6    delhi   india
```