# Determining absolute ranking with limited relative ranking data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rank

I'm trying to analyze data to determine which markets are the largest (there are ~40 markets total). Unfortunately the only data we were able to collect is asking survey respondents to rank up 6 markets in relation to each other.

I am trying to use this data to show an absolute ranking of all of the markets. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I tried to take an average score out of 6 (as there are up to 6 markets ranked in relation to each other), but because it depends on the markets the respondents choose, which is random, it is not giving an accurate answer

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you asked each respondent. Also, how did you select the respondents? How did you communicate with the respondents? What percentage actually completed the survey? In short, the first thing you need to resolve is whether your survey results are even statistically significant.

Comment: Do you mean like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/47143523/2472827?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the survey answers are consistent with one another? If not, and instead folks are just giving their personal preferences, then you run into the sorts of situations contemplated by Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning each ranking of 6 into 15 pairs of votes for one being bigger than another.

Now use some kind of Elo system to assign each market a score, indicating its estimated chances of being rated as larger than another market if the two are compared.

Then sort them by Elo rating.